# Extjs connect grid to a form

Tags: forms, extjs, grid, multi-select

I have a grid in Extjs that has list of information from database, now I want that list be processed through php, how would I make the grid act as a form, and when the list is clicked(multiselect true) the user gets the values of the list buttons, also, how would I disable the form buttons until list is seleted from grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't have enough information, so I can only give you some generic pointers.

To process the values from a grid: read the values from the grid's store and call Ext.Ajax.request passing whatever data you want from the grid.

Example:

```
var values = [];
store.each(function(rec){
  values.push({id: rec.get('id'), value: rec.get('value')});
});
Ext.Ajax.request({url: '/my/url.php', jsonData: values});
```

To disable the form buttons until you click something just pass in the disabled: true to the config. You then listen for the grid's http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-itemclick and call button.enable when that happens

Comment: ok, basically I have a grid, that has multiselect lists of items retrieved from database, all I want is a form to submit information. When user selects like 3 items from the grid list, the form should get the values of those lists, after that I will process the form. So all I need is get the values that are selected from the grid witha  submit button (to alert the values) and whenever there are no items selected from the list show the buttons disabled. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you post an example, I'll take a look.